# Water Spawned by mod does not flow

Tags: java, minecraft

So currently the water I'm spawning in my Minecraft isn't flowing. It just hovers in the air.

```
BlockPos pos = new BlockPos((myChunk.xPosition * 16) + x + 1, y + 2, (myChunk.zPosition * 16) + z);
 //Set block to current position and set it to flow.
 //State 8 is flowing water, 9 is water. 
 //TODO: Test differences between state 8 and 9.
myChunk.setBlockState(pos, BlockDynamicLiquid.getStateById(8));
```

Anyways, I've played around with various states, and trying to update both the chunk and the block. Any suggestions would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the block after spawning, e.g. `setBlockMetadataWithNotify(i, j, k, le, flag)`

Comment: Thanks, but I believe this is deprecated in 1.8. Any other suggestions?